# How to show class with hovering in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a case :

HTML :

```
<div class="a b">
    <span class="one">Success ONE</span>
    <span class="two">ONE</span>
</div>

<div class="a b">
    <span class="one">Success TWO</span>
    <span class="two">TWO</span>    
</div>
```

I want to show .two which the default is hidden. If I use CSS, I can use :

```
.two {visibility:hidden;}
.a:hover .two {visibility:visible;}
```

It works well when using CSS, but in my case, I have to comment tag this css *.a:hover .two {visibility:visible;}*.

I want to show .two with JavaScript. Could you help me to show .two when hovering .a class? (I want the same result with JavaScript like using `.a:hover .two {visibility:visible;}`)

Comment: Your class names are totally not misleading given your content strings. Nope, not at all. :)

Comment: can you explain this differently? Not sure what you are looking for

Comment: Are you trying to show the hidden `.two` on hover by JavaScript? Or switch visibility of `.one` and `.two` on hover? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the hidden .two on hover by JavaScript. @amadan

Comment: Why use js when css works?

Comment: It's just a sample case. :) Because there are 2 views. First to display in mobile view and second to display in desktop or PC. CSS works well in desktop or PC but I want to set hidden again in mobile view. I think it have the same way when accessing .a: hover .two with JS. @moo2u2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this with JS when it can be done with CSS but here you go:

CSS

```
.two {display:none;}
```

JS

```
$(".a").hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".two").toggle();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pzzqthzp/1/)

**// EDIT**

This was my original answer. I changed it to shorten the code but I will repost it:

```
$(".a").hover(function(){     
    $(this).find(".two").css({"visibility":"visible"}); 
}, function(){     
    $(this).find(".two").css({"visibility":"hidden"}); 
});
```

Comment: only on SO do people downvote you for a working answer, care to explain?

Comment: This seems to answer the OP's question, so no idea why it was downvoted.  Note that there is a difference between `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`, namely that an element with `visibility:hidden` will still take up screen space.  But that's certainly no reason for the downvote.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I think it should be mentioned that `display:none` has accessibility implications which may not be desirable depending on the specific circumstance. `visibility: hidden; position: absolute;` is preferred if you want the text readable by a screen reader.

Comment: who knows, people just look for a reason to downvote. And yeah I'm aware of the difference, not sure if it's an issue or not here considering `spans` are `inline-block` by default anyways, but thats up to the OP.

Comment: @moss can you explain what accessibility implications you're referring to?

Comment: That's a good point.  In this particular case, `display` works equally well as `visibility`.

Comment: @jmore009 I'm no expert, but it is my understanding that screen readers will not read the content of an element that is `dispaly: none;`. Just something to take into consideration when using this method. There's certainly nothing wrong with using `display: none;` if that is your desired result.

Comment: @jmore009 Hi, it works well when using your previous answer. Using hover and find. 
`$(".a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".two").css({"visibility":"visible"});
}, function(){
    $(this).find(".two").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
});`

Comment: @benz yeah, I was just trying to shorten the code. I'll repost that as the answer you chose and can you check this off as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare in the css.

```
.two {display:none;}
```

after that do something like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('> .two').css("display","block");
  },function(){
    $(this).find('> .two').css("display","none");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I'm using Javascript :

```
$(".a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".two").css({"visibility":"visible"});
}, function(){
    $(this).find(".two").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
});
```

This is the previous answer from @jmore009 before he was editing his last answer.